# How do I embed documents in a Map using Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have persistent class similar to the following:

```
public class Invoice {

    private Map<String, PurchasedItem> itemMap;

}
```

The `PurchasedItem` class looks like:

```
public class PurchasedItem {

    private String name;

    private int quantity;

}
```

Let's just say, I have good reasons not to store `PurchasedItem` objects into their own collection, and I want to store each of them under their respective parent `Invoice` objects. How do I annotate my classes so that Spring Data MongoDB automatically maps the `itemMap` correctly to something like:

```
"itemMap": {
    "tomato": {
        "name": "tomato",
        "quantity": 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate Invoice with `@Document` (in spring-mongo)

Also, an id will be required with invoice.

It will store all the fields of Invoice in a JSON format, including the map.

Comment: do you get any error? or can you share the document that is created?

Comment: The `itemMap` is recognized but it's stored as empty Map.

Comment: Can you check that itemMap has values when it is being saved? I have worked with nested structures in MongoDB without any serious concerns. Can you share the dao method? Also, check using a debugger if the object that is being saved has the map object.

Comment: I can confirm that the `itemMap` is not empty before the parent `Invoice` object is inserted in the database. I'm using a simple `MongoRepository` so there's not DAO code to speak of; it's just `MongoRepository.insert`.